# Printing spaces between characters for answer to hangman game in C#

Tags: c#

My apologies for asking yet another question, but I am struggling to get the desired output for my hangman program. When the user finds a correct letter, I would like it to display a space between letters and underscores; I can only get it to output a space after a letter and not between as desired. Also, when the secretword is guessed and the user wins, I would like the secret word to be output with spaces between the letters (eg. M A R I O). I have tried using +" " in various places, but still struggling to get the desired output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows...

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Title = ("Hangman Game");


        string[] secretWords = {
        "mario", /*"sonic", "thelegendofzelda", "donkeykong", "luigi",
        "peach", "link", "laracroft", "bowser", "kratos",
        "playstation", "nintendo", "tetris", "grandtheftauto",
        "finalfantasy", "thelastofus", "ghostoftsushima", "horizonzerodawn",
        "halo", "forza", "crashbandicoot", "worldofwarcraft", "callofduty",
        "fortnite", "animalcrossing", "doom", "metalgearsolid", "minecraft",
        "residentevil", "pacman", "spaceinvaders", "asteroids",
        "streetfighter", "mortalkombat", "supermariokart", "pokemon",
        "bioshock", "tombraider"*/
        };

        Random R = new Random();
        string secretword = secretWords[R.Next(secretWords.Length)];

        List<string> letterGuessed = new List<string>();
        int live = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To Hangman!");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter to guess for a {0} Letter Word", secretword.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("You Have {0} Lives remaining \n", live);
        Isletter(secretword, letterGuessed);
        while (live > 0)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letterGuessed.Contains(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Entered Letter [{0}] Already", input);
                Console.WriteLine("Try a Different Letter \n");
                continue;
            }
            letterGuessed.Add(input);
            if (IsWord(secretword, letterGuessed))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(secretword);
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations!");
                break;
            }
            else if (secretword.Contains(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good Entry\n");
                string letters = Isletter(secretword, letterGuessed);
                Console.Write(letters);
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That Letter Is Not In My Word");
                live -= 1;
                Console.WriteLine("You Have {0} Lives Remaining", live);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (live == 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Game Over! \nMy Secret Word is [ {0} ]", secretword);
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static bool IsWord(string secretword, List<string> letterGuessed)
    {
        bool word = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < secretword.Length; i++)
        {
            string c = Convert.ToString(secretword[i]);
            if (letterGuessed.Contains(c))
            {
                word = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return word = false;
            }
        }
        return word;
    }
    static string Isletter(string secretword, List<string> letterGuessed)
    {
        string correctletters = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < secretword.Length; i++)
        {
            string c = Convert.ToString(secretword[i]);
            if (letterGuessed.Contains(c))
            {
                correctletters += c;
            }
            else
            {
                correctletters += "_ ";
            }
        }
        return correctletters;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `correctletters += c + " ";`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first requirement but perhaps you want to use `correctletters += " _ "` instead of `correctletters += "_ "`?  Regarding the second requirement, use `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", secretword.ToUpper().ToCharArray()));` instead of `Console.WriteLine(secretword);`.

Comment: @41686d6564 Just one final question... what would be the best way to wrap this program in a loop so that the player has the option to play again or exit?

Comment: @Kieran Move the entire code that's currently in `Main` to a separate method and then in Main, use something like `do { TheMethod(); Console.WriteLine("Play again? Y/N"); } while (Console.ReadLine().Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`. This is just one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", secretword.ToUpper().ToCharArray()));

worked as expected. Many thanks @41686d6564